# Insert into list at a certain position

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

How would I add a name to a certain position in the list I have created? The list is called `names`. If that position is already taken, I would like to overwrite that position with the new name. There can only be 10 names in the list.

This is the code:

```
names = []
while True:
    print ('1 = Add Name ')
    print ('2 = Display List ')
    print ('3 = Quit \n')

    choice = input('What would you like to do: ')
    if choice == '1':
        number=input('Enter name: ')
        position= input('What position in the list would you like to add to: ')
            names.append(name) # what should i do here
        if(len(names) > 11):
            print("You cannot enter more names")
        continue
    if choice == '2':
        print(names)
        continue
    if choice == '3':
        print('Program Terminating')
        break
    else:
        print('You have entered something invalid please use numbers from 1-3 ')
        continue
```

Comment: I really don't have idea what you just asked. Please can you explain a bit

Answer (score 1):

You already have a good start to solving this. The first thing you need to do is to convert the position you receive to integer. You can do this by doing:

```
position = int(position)
```

Next you will need to insert the name at the position the user entered rather than appending it to the end of the list.

So change this line `names.append(name)` to `names.insert(position, name)`. A shortcut to doing the same thing is to do `names[position] = name`

You should examine this [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/edu/python/lists) to learn more about lists.

Answer (score 0):

You need to *preallocate* the names list so all valid positions in it can be indexed:

```
names = ['' for _ in range(10)]
```

That way, any valid index from `0` to `9` in the list can be accessed and the value there changed:

```
name = input('Enter name: ')
position = input('What position in the list would you like to change: ')
position = int(position)
if -1 < position < 10:
    names[position] = name
else:
    print('Invalid position entered')
```